# Open Graph Mobile posting stories without Canvas app

Tags: facebook, canvas, mobile, facebook-opengraph, facebook-stream-story

I hope this has not been asked before, couldnt find out.
We're developing a mobile game and we're starting to think about stories generated with open graph but we're having a doubt about our goal and whether it's going to work or not.

Our question is the following:
can we publish stories on users' wall/timeline that would be visible by friends in their feed, from an app that's only mobile and does not exist on http://facebook.com ?

We understand that this is possible when the app is on both FB and mobile, but we're not sure about mobile only.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get an answer to this.  According to my research so far adding a canvas app will allow the posts to show.  Removing it and they will not show.

Hoping you may have found a work around.

Jason

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Both.  It works if you add a canvas app and I can reproduce this behavior however I cannot find any documentation to support this one way or another.  So I think not having a canvas app SHOULD work but it does not appear to do so.  I don't think this is a definitive answer but one that might help others along that path.

Comment: Please do not use the answers to post new questions. If you have a new question, please ask it using the "Ask Question" button. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.